# Retrieve name from long string in Excel w formula Regex Powershell VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba, powershell

Export in an excel column looks like this, entire string in one cell:

```
row1: <"7412E59770E640D1B42E018421CEA48B"   <"&#58;&#58;11pt;color&#58;rgb(0 ,  0 ,  0);"  Brad Hogerheide</div   </div  

row2: <"E13F6C2BCC0C48FEA2B1799474D53743"   <"&#58;&#58;11pt;color&#58;rgb(0 ,  0 ,  0);"  Henri Le Bot</div   </div  

row3:  <"9745F6F441534D928BA82E9F1B51B99B"   <"&#58;&#58;11pt;color&#58;rgb(0 ,  0 ,  0);"   <span style="color&#58;black;"  ​ </span   <span style="color&#58;black;"  ​Michelle Bitner,&#160; <span style="&#58;Calibri ,  Arial ,  Helvetica ,  sans-serif;background-color&#58;rgb(255 ,  255 ,  255);display&#58;inline !important;"  ​Miguel Guerrero</span   </span   <br   </div   </div
```

In these rows there are some names: 1 Name in first example row: Brad Hogerheide ; Henri Le Bot in 2nd row and 2 Names in 3rd row: Michelle Bitner & ​Miguel Guerrero

I need these names to be retrieved.

I tried with function, SUBSTITUTION to add a ' ' to characters like < > , . & to do then a text to columns.

Couldn't find some references for VBA formula to apply some Regex but in Powershell.
I've saved the column in a .csv and tried some Powershell:

> ```
> $scriptRoot="C:\Users\sana\Documents\pwsh"
> ```
>
> ```
> $inputFilePath="$scriptRoot\data.csv" $outputFile="$scriptRoot\names.csv"
> ```
>
> ```
> $names=Import-Csv -Path $inputFilePath -Delimiter ' ' -Encoding Default
> ```
>
> ```
> Get-Content $inputFilePath | ForEach-Object {$_.split(" ")}
> ```
>
> ```
> foreach($col in $names){ $new=Get-Content $col | ForEach-Object {$_.split(" ")} Write-Host $new }
> ```

I get some error but also some rows:

`0);""`

`Henri`

`Le`

`Bot`

`</div`

`</div`

`"`

`"`

`<""9745F6F441534D928BA82E9F1B51B99B""`

`<""&#58;&#58;11pt;color&#58;rgb(0`

`,`

`0`

`,`

`0);""`

If I can apply some regex to get only the rows with a capital letter and concatenate them will be great.

Excel formulas but string is not equal in length and results in many columns and values not corresponding to filter.

Comment: Are you sure your file is an Excel spreadsheet? It kind of looks like the content is mangled html - possibly the result of opening a ```*.htm``` file in Excel and letting it auto-convert it. If the original file *is* html it might be easier to process *that* in Powershell direct rather than going through Excel as a middle-man…

Comment: Could you please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly?

Answer (score 0):

Given your data that, unlike your initial question, now appears to be a set of malformed html strings; I have made the assumption that a "Name" is defined by two or more words in a row, each of which is proper cased.

So you can use the following VBA routine to extract the names using Regular Expressions:

```
'set reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'  or use late binding
Option Explicit
Function ExtractNames(S As String) As String()
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
    Dim sRes() As String, I As Long
    Const sPat As String = "\b[A-Z][a-z]+(\s+[A-Z][a-z]+){1,}\b"
    
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ReDim sRes(0 To MC.Count - 1)
        I = 0
        For Each M In MC
            sRes(I) = M
            I = I + 1
        Next M
    End If
    ExtractNames = sRes
End With
End Function
```

[image]